# Rails - How to get the file path inside JavaScript in Rails app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working with a Rails app in which I am trying to specify a json file path inside my javascript. But, it seems like  I am not being able to get the file as I should get. I tried both : absolute and relative path to that file. But, nothing worked for me. I know about Rails.root which I used in my rake task to specify a file path before. But, my need this time is to specify a file path inside JavaScript in a Rails app. I am trying to locate the flare.json file. I put that in my app/assets/data/flare.json and tried this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

d3.json("/app/assets/data/flare.json", function(error, root) {
.....

}

</script>
```

But, I get the error in JavaScript console :

```
GET `http://localhost:3000/app/assets/data/flare.json 404 (Not Found)`
```

Anyone could please help me which is the correct way of specifying a file path in javaScript in Rails app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let me get this right, you want to load a json file with d3? If this is the case, consider this: The in-browser javascript environment doesn't have access to file resources on the server side. You can load them by specifically exposing files via the server and then do AJAX requests to retrieve them with javascript. So for example:

Move the file to the public directory within your app and then change the javascript to

```
d3.json("/flare.json", function(error, root) {
  .....
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct, I already solved the problem by keeping the json file public directory yesterday :-) So, accepted and +1 :-) @mortz

Answer (score 0):

Put this in config/application.rb

# Enable the asset pipeline

config.assets.enabled = true

config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/something"